# Error when running the phonegap - cordova child browser?

Tags: cordova

Im getting this error when I run the childbrowser.

Error: WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView.

Using the childbrowser it only opens it the first time I click on a link, the second time it doesn't!
It seams the .bind is firing 2 times and coases the problem.
And I read somewhere that
[webview stopLoading]; should solve the problem, I guess in the ChildBrowserViewContreller.m file.
My problem is that I don't know where to put the code? I have tested a couple of places but no luck.
Any input appreciated, thanks!

I found a solution!
In the childbrowser.js file uncomment these 4 lines:

// Show a webpage, will result in a callback to onLocationChange
ChildBrowser.prototype.showWebPage = function(loc) {
//if (typeof
 PhoneGap !== "undefined")
//{

//  PhoneGap.exec("ChildBrowserCommand.showWebPage", loc);
//}     if(typeof Cordova !== "undefined")  {
        Cordova.exec("ChildBrowserCommand.showWebPage", loc);   } };

Thats it, now it opens all the time!

Comment: could you self-answer and close this question, since it has been answered by you already?